# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

Tags: extensions, fatal-error

Why may cause this error?
Stop opening page AW blog, and displays this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /var/www/html/mysite/app/code/community/AW/Blog/Helper/Substring.php on line 18

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PHP and / or installed PHP modules, not about Magento

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `mbstring` php extension.
See this for details on how to install it: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php